# Problem with dependencies

Tags: 16.04, package-management, python, dependencies, gimp

I have a problem with dependencies on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm trying to install folder-color by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install folder-color
```

And returns:

```
folder-color : Depends: python-nautilus but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: folder-color-common but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I also tried to install or upgrade all packages but nothing.
This also happens when I try to install gimp, please help me.

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get install -f`,

Comment: Thanks George, but nothing is happening

Comment: Pls try: `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: 'Held broken packages' = Version conflict. Some non-Ubuntu or wrong-release package that you unwisely installed is preventing installation. Delete that source, and uninstall ALL packages from that source. Use the `apt-cache policy` command to figure out the bad source. Read the manpage for usage.

Comment: @Black_FireFox you say "Nothing happens", but while I believe that your situation hasn't improve, you are holding back the error message the terminal returns to you. Please, give us the error message for each thing you try, even if you feel the situation didn't improve. The error message helps us to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)